# Retrieve website table to import into Excel

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I am learning how to retrieve tables from websites into excel.
I usually use the web query function, but sometimes excel doesn't see these tables.
So I am trying to write VBA queries by reading lots of posts, but I have limited knowledge and would appreciate your help.

Website link :
[https://www.zacks.com/stocks/industry-rank/sectors/?icid=stocks-industry-nav_tracking-zcom-main_menu_wrapper-zacks_sector_rank](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1iHS.jpg)

Here's what I wrote so far :

```
Public Sub GetInfo()

Dim IE As New InternetExplorer, clipboard As Object
With IE
    .Visible = True
    .navigate "https://www.zacks.com/stocks/industry-rank/sectors/?icid=stocks-industry-nav_tracking-zcom-main_menu_wrapper-zacks_sector_rank"

    While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

    Set clipboard = GetObject("New:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")
    With .document.getElementById("industry_sector_data_table").contentDocument
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1) = .getElementsByClassName("industry_sector_data_table")(0).innerText
        clipboard.SetText .getElementsByTagName("table")(2).outerHTML
        clipboard.PutInClipboard
    End With

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 1).PasteSpecial
    .Quit
End With
```

End Sub

Here's a picture of the site where the table is located :
[image]

First thing, I need to click on the Earnings tab (no idea if it's even possible)

Second item is how do I select the number of entries to 100 ? This is for other tables I need to retrieve in the future. This one actually doesn't need it.

[image]

Third, the location of the table. I have "industry_sector_date_table" as table id. Not sure how to actually get the info "td", in this example 80.77%, 83.33% and all the other ones.
The table seem to be number 2.
I also read on one post that there is a way to do it without opening the web browser, not sure if I understood that correctly. Is it possible ?
Hope anybody can help from here.
Thanks

[image]

Comment: Try this [URL](https://www.zacks.com/data_handler/sector/z2_sector_data.php?p=0&t=3) to access the content using xhr.

Comment: Love this site !! Always someone that comes up with an easy one. Is this kind of link available for any website ? Any suggestion how to filter out the info into an excel table ?

Comment: Actually...how did you find that link ?

Comment: You should check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65096455/vba-web-scraping-cant-acces-table-web-page) to get an idea how you can process the json response in order to write the same in an excel worksheet.